# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

How to solve this error?

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Comment: user not logged in first check if user is logged in ```{{ Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->name : '' }}```

Comment: `Auth::check()` is the preferred method.

Comment: I have now this error `{{ asset('uploads/'.Auth::user()->image) }}`  `Trying to get property 'image' of non-object`

Comment: use `Auth::check()` block write all the codes that depend on `Auth::user()` inside it

Comment: I use this method `{{ asset('uploads/' .Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->image : '' ) }}`  and also I have this error `Trying to get property 'image' of non-object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `Auth::check()`, you can use blade directives take a [look](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives)

```
@guest
    // Show content if  unauthenticated
@endguest

@auth
    // The data only available for auth user
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endauth
```